# Maven Spring Boot multi modules

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to configure Maven to use Spring Boot with multi modules. I am new to Maven and Spring Boot Stuff and I am not sure how this works together. So I started to create a simple Structure. At the beginning I want to start with one Module.

```
myApp
|
|--web module
|----java
|------controller
|------Application.java (Main Methode)
|----resources
|------templates
|--------index.html
|------application.propperties
|------log4j2.json
|----webapp
|----pom.xml
|--pom.xml
```

Here is my parent pom.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.benteler.apps.saplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>saplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>saplication</name>
    <description>Shows SAP Reports</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Database Driver-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <version>5.1.36</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
                <version>6</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- JSON handling-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>saplication-snapshot</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here my main module pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>saplication</artifactId>
        <groupId>net.benteler.apps.saplication</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>web</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Logging with Log4J-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <!-- Data handling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Database Driver-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Unit testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON handling-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Templating - deliver JSP-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>saplication-snapshot</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

To my application.propperties I add

```
spring.view.prefix = /templates/
spring.view.suffix = .html
```

And my Application.java looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hallo");
        SpringApplication.run(SaplicationApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MainController.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String index(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        logger.info("/test");
        logger.debug("Hello world - debug log");
        logger.info("Hello world - info log");
        logger.warn("Hello world - warn log");
        logger.error("Hello world - error log");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

When I start the application the mapping is working

```
Mapped "{[/test]}" onto public java.lang.String saplication.controller.MainController.index(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView)
```

And the log messages are shown

```
[INFO ] 2015-10-06 08:41:37.477 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] MainController - /test
[INFO ] 2015-10-06 08:41:37.478 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] MainController - Hello world - info log
[WARN ] 2015-10-06 08:41:37.478 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] MainController - Hello world - warn log
[ERROR] 2015-10-06 08:41:37.478 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] MainController - Hello world - error log
```

But when I type http://localhost:8080/test i just see the message

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Oct 06 08:41:37 CEST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

On the first view it seems that everything works well but the problem witch I have is that Spring does not find my index.html Template.

I readlly don't know what is wrong in my config ! So I need your help.

Comment: Can you try it with [http://localhost:8080/<yourAppName>/test](http://localhost:8080/<yourAppName>/test) and also with the snapshot name of maven. [http://localhost:8080/<yourAppName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT>/test](http://localhost:8080/<yourAppName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT>/test)

Comment: do you have your app in github or somewhere else?

Comment: seems like the jsp page is not exist (`index.jsp`). so, can you try to create it and check it again?

Comment: Your project does not follow default Maven project structure. If you're new to Maven start with single module approach first. After you understand Maven basics, code some simple Spring Boot application - try then with multimodule.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: change your IDE's working DIR to your module, because spring-boot embed tomcat use top-level path plus yours define to route web root.

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes to your **Application.java**

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(Application.class);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

    }
```

**SpringBootServletInitializer**

This is required to run the web application. This will enable the servlet container and bind your application to the servlet container.

**Update :-**

To run your main module(web module), you have to goto on that directory and after that run your project using `mvn spring-boot:run` command.

**Example:-** **1.** [me@linuxbox myApp] $ `cd /web` **2.** [me@linuxbox web] $ `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: This is only required if you're building a war and deploying it to a standalone container. It's unnecessary if you're following the recommended and default approach of using an embedded container.

Answer (score 0):

Put your resources in the folder `src/main/resources` within the web module. This is the default Maven structure for resources.